# Explode convert in 2D matriz for insert database - PHP

Tags: php

I have the form insertion function in the database in PHP below:

**SCRIPT**

```
   <?php

    $MULTIVALUE = $_POST[multi_id];    

    if ($MULTIVALUE == "YES") {

            $servers = explode(';', $_POST[server]);

            if( !empty( $servers ) ) {

                for ($i = 0; $i <= count($servers); $i++) {

                    echo $servers[$i];

                    $query = "INSERT INTO tb_excep_baseline (email,firstname,lastname,title,excep,server,client,date_excep,typeexcep) VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]',
                    '$_POST[title]','$_POST[exception]','$servers[$i]','$_POST[clients]','$date','$_POST[type_id]')";
                    $result = pg_query($query);
                    $query_excep = "update tb_get_gap set exception = 'YES' where hostname = '$_POST[server]'";
                    $result_excep = pg_query($query_excep);

                }
            }

        } else {

            $query = "INSERT INTO tb_excep_baseline (email,firstname,lastname,title,excep,server,client,date_excep,typeexcep) VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]',
            '$_POST[title]','$_POST[exception]','$_POST[server]','$_POST[clients]','$date','$_POST[type_id]')";
            $result = pg_query($query);
            $query_excep = "update tb_get_gap set exception = 'YES' where hostname = '$_POST[server]'";
            $result_excep = pg_query($query_excep);

        }

    ?>
```

Currently the form takes the **HOSTNAME** input, and `explode()` with `;` and insert this list into the database

[image]

**GOAL**

I would like it to take the same input and break it with; but creating **column A** *(hostname)* and **column B** *(problem)*, and insert it in the database, where:

**COLUMN A** = `server`
**COLUMN** B = `excep`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to fetch two values in one loop-run, like this:

```php
$input = 'server1;problem1;server2;problem2;server3;problem3';

$parts = explode(';', $input);
$partCount = count($parts);
$serverProblems = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $partCount; $i++) {
    $serverProblems[] = [
        'server' => $parts[$i],
        'problem' => $parts[++$i], // note the second increment here
    ];
}

var_dump($serverProblems);
```

output:

```php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["server"]=>
    string(7) "server1"
    ["problem"]=>
    string(8) "problem1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["server"]=>
    string(7) "server2"
    ["problem"]=>
    string(8) "problem2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["server"]=>
    string(7) "server3"
    ["problem"]=>
    string(8) "problem3"
  }
}
```

Comment: @LuisHenrique It is encouraged that you upvote and/or accept an answer that solved your problem ;)